# Page Not Found after sf_guard success_signin_url

Tags: configuration, symfony1, sfguard, symfony-1.3

After successful registration using sfGuard, I land on "sf/sf_admin/css/main.css" with 404 message.

Is there any way to set the `app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url` to go to homepage?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/4_0_2?tab=plugin_readme) of the plugin (at the bottom), you can define it in your `app.yml`:

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    success_signin_url:      @my_route?param=value # the plugin use the referer as default
    success_signout_url:     module/action         # the plugin use the referer as default
```